# How to grow a grafted avocado in bad soil?

Tags: fruit-trees, soil, avocado, soil-test

I live in St.Croix  and want to plant into the ground a grafted avocado tree that is 2'ft  (60 cm) high. I live close to the ocean. I see lots of mango trees in the neighborhood, but few if any avocado trees.

1. How to I check to see if the soil is good for this type of tree?
2. What do I need to amend the soil if necessary?
   Thank you

Comment: Some more info you might add (would be helpful): what variety of avocado tree do you have: Guatemalan, West Indian, Mexican or maybe a mix (ie Guatemalan grafted to a Mexican)? In general, they are hardy tree's that can grow in a variety of soil types but they need good drainage.